# Django form __init__ method appears to be called twice

Tags: python, django, validation, form-submit, python-multithreading

On one of my Django webpages, I am displaying an icon for each instance of a particular model (`Meeting`) in the database (one icon per instance of the model).

When the user clicks one of the icons, a form is displayed elsewhere on the page to allow the user to enter details about that particular instance of the model. Once they have entered all of the details for the fields fields on the form, they can press an 'Upload' button to upload the information entered to the database (and save the information to that instance of the model).

When the form is submitted, the page will refresh, displaying an icon for each instance of a particular model. If the user clicks an existing icon, and makes a change to any of the fields on its form, and clicks 'Upload', a new instance of that model is created with the form populated with those amended fields.

Each click to the 'Upload' button should create one more instance of the `Meeting` model in the database. Each of the fields on the form represent one of the `Meeting` model's attributes.

I have two buttons on the form, for attaching image files to the instance of the `Meeting`, one of them currently works- when I use it to attach an image, and click 'Upload', the page is refreshed, and the image is displayed attached to the form for that instance of the model.

However, when I click 'Upload' after attaching an image to using the other button, the page is refreshed and several additional instances of the `Meeting` model are displayed on the webpage, with all of the fields for their forms left blank, and no image file attached (although one is also created with all of the fields saved as entered, and with the image file attached).

While trying to work out why more than one instance of the `Meeting` object is created when uploading an image via this particular button, I added some debug to my code, in particular, to the form that I'm using to upload this information & these images to the database:

```
class BudgetPresentationForm(ValidatedForm):
    """ Provides the form for the formset BudgetPresentationFormset """
    presentation_minutes = EasyText(field_class="medium", label='Client presentation notes')
    presentation_date = MoonDateTimeField(required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', attrs=({'class':'datetimepicker presentation_date', 'name':'presentation_date2'})))
    presenter1 = forms.CharField()
    presenter2 = forms.CharField()
    presenter3 = forms.CharField()
    presenter4 = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Budget
        fields = ('presentation_minutes', 'presenter1', 'presenter2', 'presenter3', 'presenter4', 'presentation_date', 'pdf_package_dep')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        budget = self.instance

        if hasattr(budget, 'id'):
            self.presenters = budget.presenters.all()

            if budget.presentation_date:
                print("Budget meeting: ", budget.meeting)
                pres_meeting = budget.meeting or Meeting.objects.create(project=budget.project, purpose='7')
                print("Meeting created in projects/forms.py BudgetPresentationForm (line 1055): ", pres_meeting)
                self.pres_meeting_id = pres_meeting.id
                self.pres_meeting_creator = pres_meeting.event_creator or ''
                if not budget.meeting:
                    budget.meeting = pres_meeting
                    budget.save()
                if not budget.meeting or not pres_meeting.date:
                    pres_meeting.date = budget.presentation_date
                    pres_meeting.save()
                print("Meeting object is: ", pres_meeting.id)
                #print("Process ID: ", os.getpid())
        else: self.presenters = []

        super(BudgetPresentationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # if hasattr(self, 'pres_meeting_id'): self.fields['presentation_date'].widget.attrs['data-meeting-id'] = self.pres_meeting_id
        self.fields['presentation_date'].widget.attrs.update({'data-meeting-id': getattr(self,'pres_meeting_id', ''), 'data-meeting-creator': getattr(self,'pres_meeting_creator', '')})

        initial_presenters = [(e.id, e.full_name) for e in self.presenters]+[None, None, None, None]#[(None, ''), (None, ''), (None, ''), (None, '')] # Always at least four so that first four can populate form fields
        if initial_presenters[0]: self.fields['presenter1'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[initial_presenters[0]], current_id='', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant='', class_name="autocomplete", label='Who is presenting')
        else: self.fields['presenter1'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[(None, '')], current_id='*', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant=' instant', class_name="autocomplete", label='Who is presenting')
        if initial_presenters[1]: self.fields['presenter2'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[initial_presenters[1]], current_id='', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant='', class_name="autocomplete", label='')
        else: self.fields['presenter2'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[(None, '')], current_id='*', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant=' instant', class_name="autocomplete", label='')
        if initial_presenters[2]: self.fields['presenter3'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[initial_presenters[2]], current_id='', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant='', class_name="autocomplete", label='')
        else: self.fields['presenter3'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[(None, '')], current_id='*', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant=' instant', class_name="autocomplete", label='')
        if initial_presenters[3]: self.fields['presenter4'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[initial_presenters[3]], current_id='', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant='', class_name="autocomplete", label='')
        else: self.fields['presenter4'] = FlexiSelect(initial=[(None, '')], current_id='*', url_code='ee', choices=[], required=False, instant=' instant', class_name="autocomplete", label='')

BudgetPresentationFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, Budget, form=BudgetPresentationForm, max_num=30, extra=1, can_delete=False)
```

But when I click the 'Submit' button for this form, having entered the information into all of the fields, and attached the image files to the form, my console shows that the code inside:

```
if budget.presentation_date:
```

is run twice... i.e. I get the same output duplicated in the console with what should be only one execution of this code (i.e. when it's executed when reloading the webpage, following the form submission).

The console output shows:

> ('Budget meeting: ', )
>
> ('Meeting created in projects/forms.py BudgetPresentationForm (line 1055): ', )
>
> ('Meeting object is: ', 11012L)
>
> ('Budget meeting: ', )
>
> ('Meeting created in projects/forms.py BudgetPresentationForm (line 1055): ', )
>
> ('Meeting object is: ', 11078L)

Having Google'd why this may be happening, it appears that it might be that the code is being executed by two separate threads, and this is why it's being run twice...

Is this the case? Why is it happening if so? How can I ensure that the code is only run once, and that I don't end up with duplicate information in my database?

I've not worked with threads much before, so am not really sure how/ what to do about this....

**Edit**

As requested in the comment & answer- the places where I am using the `formset` are- in the `view` for `concept` (which is the page on which I am displaying these Presentations & the form to enter details for a `Meeting`):

```
def concept(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('budget_versions').get(id=project_id)
    deposit = Deposit.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    end_details = EndDetails.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentation_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(prefix="presentations", instance=project, queryset=presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'presentations': presentations,
        'presentation_formset': presentation_formset,
        'drawing_formset': drawing_formset,
        'deposit_form': DepositInfoForm(instance=deposit),
        'ended_form': EndDetailsForm(instance=end_details),
        'budget_notes_form': BudgetNotesForm(instance=project.budget_overview),
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/concept.html', context)
```

and in the `upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):` `view`, (which is the `view` used to try and upload the PDFs to the form (i.e. what I am using to 'attach' a PDF to the form):

```
def upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    print("Value of project in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", project)

    if request.method == 'POST':

    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    print("Value of presentations in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

    if drawing_formset:
        print "Before", [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]           
        try:
            for drawing_form in drawing_formset: #ERF(24/01/2017 @ 1610) This line is what's causing the MultiValueDictKeyError
                print 'drawing for loop entered in upload_budget_pdfs() - line 1034 '
                if drawing_form.instance.budget:
                    print 'if statement entered - line 1036 '
                    print 'Instance: ', drawing_form.instance.budget
                    drawing = drawing_form.save(commit=False)
                    drawing.budget = drawing_form.instance.budget
                    drawing.save()
                print drawing, [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
        except Exception as e:
            print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
    else: 
        print("Drawing formset not valid. ", drawing_formset.errors)

    budget_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project, prefix="presentations")

    if budget_formset:
        try:
            # Add a boolean so that budget is only added to form once
            budgetSaved = False
            for budget_form in budget_formset:

                if budget_form:
                    if budgetSaved == False:
                        print 'if statement entered - line 1081 '

                        budget = budget_form.save(commit=False)

                        budget.save()
                        budgetSaved = True

        except Exception as e:
            print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
    else:
        print("Budget formset not valid. ", budget_formset.errors)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects:concept', args=[project_id]))
```

Comment: No, a request is served by a single thread. Surely this is because you have a formset containing multiple forms?

Comment: Ok- yes, I have a formset containing multiple forms- there will be a form for each presentation displayed on the page (i.e. a form for each `Meeting` object). The form is only displayed on the page when the user clicks the 'Edit' button for a given presentation... But at the moment, two additional 'presentations' (which are representative of the `Meeting` object) are displayed on the webpage whenever I click the form 'Upload' button to upload a 'Budget' image to the `Meeting`... any ideas why?

Comment: You probably need to show the view.

Comment: I've added the `views` that are using the `formset`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what the issue is you are concerned about. Is it that you don't want blank forms in your formset? Then use the [`extra` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets) to the formset_factory.

Comment: No- the issue is when either adding a new presentation to the page, or editing an existing one using the form (there is a separate instance of the form for each individual presentation- i.e. if I click 'Edit' on Presentation 1, it's form is displayed, and any details that were previously entered into it are populated; if I click 'Edit' on Presentation 2, it's form is displayed with any stored details populated; if I click 'New Presentation', a blank form is displayed). If I click the 'Done' button on the form, the details entered into the form are saved for that presentation.

Comment: But what is wrong with that? It sounds exactly what you would want to happen. What are you expecting?

Comment: Similarly, if I edit an existing Presentation, and change any of the details on its form, and click 'Done', the existing presentation is changed- and its populated form displays the amended details. However, if I attach an image file to the form using the 'Choose File' button for a Budget PDF, (selecting the file using the file explorer window that opens), the form shows that the file has been attached, but when I click the 'Upload' button on the form, to upload the file to the database model, the page is refreshed, and two additional presentations are displayed.

Comment: The Presentation that I edited shows it's form is empty, two additional presentations have been created (I didn't want to add any new ones, just edit an existing one), and the details entered have been added to the second new presentation, and the image file has not been uploaded...

Comment: What I am expecting to happen is, if I 'edit' an existing presentation (change details of the meeting, or upload a Budget PDF file or Drawing file to it), that presentation should still be displayed on the page, just that the form should show the amended details. It should not create additional presentations. Similarly, if I 'add' a new presentation, and upload a Budget PDF file to it, only the one presentation should be added- at the moment, it is adding a total of 3 presentations to the page every time I click 'Upload' after attaching a Budget PDF file to the form.

Comment: It behaves in exactly the correct way when uploading a 'Drawing' file to the exact same form, and pressing the exact same 'Upload' button after attaching it... although there are separate buttons for attaching a Budget PDF & attaching a Drawing file, maybe the issue is to do with how they are attached to the form?

Answer (score 0):

By formset meaning you have a form which will be repeated for a set of items. You have to show the code where/how you are using that formset. Possibly that is where the point of origin of the issue lies.

[Link to Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: The formset is defined in forms.py, just below the definition of the form, as shown in my OP: `BudgetPresentationFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, Budget, form=BudgetPresentationForm, max_num=30, extra=1, can_delete=False)`. I've added the `views` where I'm using the form & formset to my OP too.